# How to delete row data in localstorage respect to row data

Tags: javascript, php, html

This Is My HTML Input boxes

```
  <div class="box-body col-sm-12">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtSlNo" id="txtSlNo" value="1">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
   <label for="Date" class="control-label">Date:</label>
    <input type="text" class="text-right" name="date[]" id="date" value="<?
          php  echo date("Y/M/D")?>">
  </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="name" class="control-Service">Service:</label>
               <!-- <input type="text" name="txtService" class="text-right" 
 id="txtService"> -->


                <select id="txtService" class="txtService" 
 name="txtService[]">
                    <option value="" onmouseout="" ="">Select 
Service</option>
                    <?php

        $query="SELECT * FROM service_master";
           $results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
              foreach ($results as $sd_name) {

    ?>

<option value="<?php echo $sd_name["sd_name"];?>";?>
<?php echo $sd_name["sd_name"];?></option>
<?php
}
                   ?>

                  </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="name" class="control-Charge">Charge:</label>



               <select class="txtCharge" id="txtCharge" name="txtCharge[]">
                  <!-- onchange="fetchDesignation(this)" -->
                    <option value="" onmouseout="" ="">Select 
 Charge</option>
                    <?php



        $query="SELECT * FROM charge_master";
           $results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
              foreach ($results as $cd_name) {

 ?>

<option value="<?php echo $cd_name["cd_name"];?>";?>
 <?php echo $cd_name["cd_name"];?></option>
 <?php
  }
                   ?>

                  </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name"  class="control-label">Amount:</label>
                <input type="text" size="7" class="text-right" 
 name="txtAmount[]" id="txtAmount" oninput="calculate()" onkeypress="return 
 isNumber(event);">
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Unit:</label>
             <input type="text" size="7" name="txtUnit[]" class="text-right" 
id="txtUnit" oninput="calculate()" value="1" onkeypress="return 
isNumber(event);">
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Total:</label>
              <input type="text" size="7" name="txtTotal[]" class="text-
     right"  id="txtTotal" oninput="calculate();" oninput="addTotal();" 
    readonly>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <br>

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="button" value="add"  name="tableAdd" id="tableAdd" 
           class="btn btn-primary add add1"> 
          </div>


      </div>
```

Next is my LocalStorage structure

```
function save(){
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
var datehistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("date")) || [];
datehistory.push(date);
localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(datehistory));


var service = document.getElementById("txtService").value;
var servicehistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("service")) || [];
servicehistory.push(service);
localStorage.setItem("service", JSON.stringify(servicehistory));

var charge = document.getElementById("txtCharge").value;
var chargehistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("charge")) || [];
chargehistory.push(charge);
localStorage.setItem("charge", JSON.stringify(chargehistory));

var amount = document.getElementById("txtAmount").value;
var amounthistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("amount")) || [];
amounthistory.push(amount);
localStorage.setItem("amount", JSON.stringify(amounthistory));

var unit = document.getElementById("txtUnit").value;
var unithistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("unit")) || [];
unithistory.push(unit);
localStorage.setItem("unit", JSON.stringify(unithistory));

var total = document.getElementById("txtTotal").value;
var totalhistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("total")) || [];
totalhistory.push(total);
localStorage.setItem("total", JSON.stringify(totalhistory));
}
```

Next is code dynamic generation of table rows

```
$("#tableAdd").click(function(){

var sl_no = ($('#tabledata tr').length) - 1;

        lclCount++;
        sl_no++;

        var date = [];
        var service = [];
        var charge = [];
        var amount = [];
        var unit = [];
        var total = [];
        var markup = [];


          // var date = [input["name"]]
        date = $("#date").val();
        // var date = new Array($("#date").val());
        service = $("#txtService").val();
        // var service = new Array($('#txtService').val());
        charge = $("#txtCharge").val();
        amount = $("#txtAmount").val();
        unit = $("#txtUnit").val();
        total = $("#txtTotal").val();
        markup = "<tr><td class='mar'><input type='checkbox' class='chk' 
name='record' id='"+ lclCount +"'></td><td name='slno' class='slno' id 
='slno-"+sl_no+"'>" 
         + sl_no + "</td><td class='date1' name='date1'>"
         + date + "</td><td class='service' name='service'>"
         + service + "</td><td class='charge' name='charge'>"
         + charge + "</td><td name='amount'>"
         + amount + "</tserviced><td name='unit'>"
         + unit + "</td><td name='total' id='txtTot-"+lclCount+"'>"
         + parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
       // alert(innerText);
     var data = $("#tabledata").append(markup);

});
```

Below code represents the Delete code

```
 $(".delete-row").click(function(){

        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){

          if($(this).is(":checked")){
         var ele =$(this).parent();
         var lclSlNo = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html();
         var lclDate = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(3)').html();
         var lclService = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-
  type(4)').html();
         var lclCharge = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-
type(5)').html();
         var lclAmount = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-
type(6)').html();
         var lclUnit = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(7)').html();
         var lclTotal = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(8)').html();

         var lclDateSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("date"));
         var lclServiceSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("service"));
         var lclChargeSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("charge"));
         var lclAmountSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("amount"));
         var lclUnitSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("unit"));
         var lclTotalSto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("total"));

          if(lclDateSto == lclDate && lclServiceSto == lclService && 
    lclChargeSto == lclCharge && lclAmountSto == lclAmount && lclUnitSto == 
  lclUnit && lclTotalSto == lclTotal){
            // alert(localStorage.getItem(lclDateSto));
            var d = localStorage.removeItem("date");
            // alert(d);
            localStorage.removeItem("service");
            localStorage.removeItem("charge");
            localStorage.removeItem("amount");
            localStorage.removeItem("unit");
            localStorage.removeItem("total");
            alert("true");
          }else{
          alert("false");

         }



            }

        });
      });
```

Here is My image that shows my front end structure about checkbox and input boxes buttons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWsBq.png)
Now I explain, I am generating the HTML table rows dynamically with markup and I able to insert the data into localStorage successfully and if I delete row data using checkbox that row is deleted successfully that fine Now my Question is If I delete row data using checkbox that same time data in localStorage should get delete with respect to the table row that happening correctly If table has only one row and If table has 2 or more rows that time not able to delete the data from the localStorage. Answers from your side will be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your question is about localStorage, then you really want to reduce your problem to one where you reproduce it purely with JavaScript, since localStorage is not coupled to HTML, and *absolutely* unrelated to PHP

Comment: Thank you for response about language.